# Get total number of rows of a nested gridview using jquery - ASP.NET C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have gridview (gvShop) with a sub gridview (gvuser) as it's itemtemplate as shown below. Now I want to check that if that sub gridview is empty or not. How can I do it using jquery ?
I'm getting the total number of rows of gvshop using `var totalRows = $("#<%=gvShop.ClientID %> tr").length;` But not gvuser.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvShop" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
DataKeyNames="c_id" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" 
ShowHeader="False">
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField >
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
    <div style="float:left;width:90%">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvuser" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" ShowFooter="true" Width="80%" HeaderStyle-Height="30px" >
     <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SNo"  ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Height="25px">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex + 1%></ItemTemplate>           
 </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="54%"  HeaderText="Airlines" ItemStyle-Height="25px">   
<ItemTemplate >
<asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server"  Text = '<%#Eval("user_name")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                     <FooterStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center" />  
                </asp:GridView></div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100%" DataField="cat_name"  /> 
</Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: *How can I do it using jquery* Then why it is tagged to `c#` tag?

Comment: You need to search for `table tr` inside each `$("#<%=gvShop.ClientID %> tr")`

Comment: Do you want a **total** of nested rows or a count for each nested table?

Comment: count of each nested table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a class before nested gridview of "gvuser" and use each loop in jquery

Check below code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvShop" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                DataKeyNames="c_id" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
                ShowHeader="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <div style="float:left;width:90%" class="userGrid">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvuser" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" ShowFooter="true" Width="80%" HeaderStyle-Height="30px">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SNo" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Height="25px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex + 1%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="54%" HeaderText="Airlines" ItemStyle-Height="25px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("user_name")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100%" DataField="cat_name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now for jQuery Use below Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=gvShop.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('.userGrid table tr').length > 0) {
            console.log('Yes, User Data has row');
        } else {
            console.log('No, User Data has not any row');
        }
    });//end of loop

});
```

Here 'each' loop will check all parent rows one by one to check that class '.userGrid' has any table or not.

Comment: Note that this will iterate over **all rows** nested or not. You may get a significant performance hit for large tables when the nested table are also large. You could streamline this using the child selector  `>` which will only then iterate the direct children.

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure will look like the below.

To get a count of  all nested rows use:

```
$("#<%=gvShop.ClientID %> table tr").length;
```

To get an array of row counts in each nested table use:

```
var arrRowCount = jQuery.map($("#<%=gvShop.ClientID %> table"), function(table) {
      return $(table).find("tr").length;
    });
```

**Example**

```js
var totalRows = $("#gvShop table tr").length;
console.log("Total Nested Rows: " + totalRows);

var arrRowCount = jQuery.map($("#gvShop table"), function(table) {
  //You add extra functionality in here if you need it
  //for each table;
  return $(table).find("tr").length;
});

console.log("Nested table row counts:")
console.log(arrRowCount);

//Some extra stuff

//Get all rows without tables
var arrRowsWithOutTable = jQuery.map($("#gvShop>tbody>tr"), function(row) {
  //You add extra functionality in here if you need it
  //for each table;
  if ($(row).find("table").length === 0) {
    return row;
  }
});

console.log("Rows Without Tables")
console.log(arrRowsWithOutTable);

//Get all rows with tables
var arrRowsWithTable = jQuery.map($("#gvShop>tbody>tr"), function(row) {
  //You add extra functionality in here if you need it
  //for each table;
  if ($(row).find("table").length > 0) {
    return row;
  }
});

console.log("Rows With Tables")
console.log(arrRowsWithTable);

//Get Indicies of rows with tables
//Get all rows with tables
var arrIndicies = jQuery.map($("#gvShop>tbody>tr"), function(row,index) {  
  if ($(row).find("table").length > 0) {
    return index;
  }
});

console.log("Rows indicies With Tables")
console.log(arrIndicies);

//Get Indicies of rows with tables with count
//Get all rows with tables
var arrIndicies = jQuery.map($("#gvShop>tbody>tr"), function(row,index) {  
  if ($(row).find("table").length > 0) {
    return {"index" : index, "count" : $(row).find("table tr").length} ;
  }
});

console.log("Rows indicies With Tables")
console.log(arrIndicies);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="gvShop">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="gvShop_01_gvUser">
        <tr>
          <td>01 - 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>01 - 02</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="gvShop_02_gvUser">
        <tr>
          <td>02 - 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>02 - 02</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="gvShop_03_gvUser">
        <tr>
          <td>03 - 01</td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sorry No table here
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="gvShop_04_gvUser">
        <tr>
          <td>04 - 01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>04 - 02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>04 - 03</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sorry No table here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If note the use of `#<%=gvShop.ClientID %>` to get around Webform name mangling. Alternatively use a class as an identifier.